# Did prophet Muhammad ever claim to be the best man of all time?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, sunnah

Did prophet Muhammad in his narrations ever claim to be the best man of all time?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones no he is asking here about if it's mentioned in the sunnah ... !

Comment: FWIW best as in the most humble of all. He saw his poorness before Allah the most and therefore he was the best...

Answer (score -1):

> Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger peace be upon him as saying: I
>   shall be pre-eminent amongst the descendants of Adam on the Day of
>   Resurrection and I will be the first intercessor and the first whose
>   intercession will be accepted (by Allah).
>
> عن هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏
>   أَنَا سَيِّدُ وَلَدِ آدَمَ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ وَأَوَّلُ مَنْ
>   يَنْشَقُّ عَنْهُ الْقَبْرُ وَأَوَّلُ شَافِعٍ وَأَوَّلُ مُشَفَّعٍ ‏"‏
>   ‏.‏
>
> [muslim 43:3](https://sunnah.com/muslim/43/3)

---

> It was narrated from Abu Sa’eed that the Messenger of allah peace be upon him said:
>   “I am the leader of the sons of Adam, and it is no boast. I will be
>   the first one for whom the earth will be split open on the Day of
>   Resurrection, and it is no boast. I will be the first to intercede and
>   the first whose intercession will be accepted, and it is no boast. The
>   banner of praise will be in my hand on the Day of Resurrection, and it
>   is no boast.”
>
> عَنْ أَبِي سَعِيدٍ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ
>   ‏ "‏ أَنَا سَيِّدُ وَلَدِ آدَمَ وَلاَ فَخْرَ وَأَنَا أَوَّلُ مَنْ
>   تَنْشَقُّ الأَرْضُ عَنْهُ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ وَلاَ فَخْرَ وَأَنَا
>   أَوَّلُ شَافِعٍ وَأَوَّلُ مُشَفَّعٍ وَلاَ فَخْرَ وَلِوَاءُ الْحَمْدِ
>   بِيَدِي يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ وَلاَ فَخْرَ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> [sunan ibn majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1344490)

---

> Abu Huraira reported: While a Jew was selling goods, he was given
>   something which he did not accept or he did not agree (to accept) that
>   'Abdul 'Azlz (one of the narrators) is doubtful about it. He (the Jew)
>   said: By Allah, Who chose Moses (peace be upon him) among mankind. A
>   person from the Ansar heard it and gave a blow at his face saying:
>   (You have the audacity) to say: By Him Who chose Moses amongst
>   mankind, whereas Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) is living amongst us. The Jew
>   went to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and said: Abu'l-Qasim, I am a Dhimmi and
>   (thus need your protection) by a covenant, and added: Such and such
>   person has given a blow upon my face. Thereupon Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)
>   said: Why did you give a blow on his face? He said: Allah's Messenger,
>   this man said: By Him Who chose Moses (peace be upon him) amongst
>   mankind, whereas you are living amongst us. Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)
>   became angry and signs of anger could be seen on his face, and then
>   said: Don't make distinction amongst the Prophets of Allah. When the
>   horn will be blown and whatever is in the heavens and the earth would
>   swoon but he whom Allah grants exception, then another horn will be
>   blown and I would be the first amongst those who would recover and
>   Moses (peace be upon him) would be catching hold of the Throne and I
>   do not know whether it is a compensation for that when he swooned on
>   the Day of Tur or he would be resurrected before me and I do not say
>   that anyone is more excellent than Yunus son of Matta (peace he upon
>   him).
>
> عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ بَيْنَمَا يَهُودِيٌّ يَعْرِضُ سِلْعَةً
>   لَهُ أُعْطِيَ بِهَا شَيْئًا كَرِهَهُ أَوْ لَمْ يَرْضَهُ - شَكَّ عَبْدُ
>   الْعَزِيزِ - قَالَ لاَ وَالَّذِي اصْطَفَى مُوسَى عَلَيْهِ السَّلاَمُ
>   عَلَى الْبَشَرِ ‏.‏ قَالَ فَسَمِعَهُ رَجُلٌ مِنَ الأَنْصَارِ فَلَطَمَ
>   وَجْهَهُ - قَالَ - تَقُولُ وَالَّذِي اصْطَفَى مُوسَى عَلَيْهِ
>   السَّلاَمُ عَلَى الْبَشَرِ وَرَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم بَيْنَ
>   أَظْهُرِنَا قَالَ فَذَهَبَ الْيَهُودِيُّ إِلَى رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى
>   الله عليه وسلم فَقَالَ يَا أَبَا الْقَاسِمِ إِنَّ لِي ذِمَّةً
>   وَعَهْدًا ‏.‏ وَقَالَ فُلاَنٌ لَطَمَ وَجْهِي ‏.‏ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ
>   اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ لِمَ لَطَمْتَ وَجْهَهُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالَ
>   ‏.‏ قَالَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ وَالَّذِي اصْطَفَى مُوسَى عَلَيْهِ
>   السَّلاَمُ عَلَى الْبَشَرِ وَأَنْتَ بَيْنَ أَظْهُرِنَا ‏.‏ قَالَ
>   فَغَضِبَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم حَتَّى عُرِفَ الْغَضَبُ
>   فِي وَجْهِهِ ثُمَّ قَالَ ‏"‏ لاَ تُفَضِّلُوا بَيْنَ أَنْبِيَاءِ
>   اللَّهِ فَإِنَّهُ يُنْفَخُ فِي الصُّورِ فَيَصْعَقُ مَنْ فِي
>   السَّمَوَاتِ وَمَنْ فِي الأَرْضِ إِلاَّ مَنْ شَاءَ اللَّهُ - قَالَ -
>   ثُمَّ يُنْفَخُ فِيهِ أُخْرَى فَأَكُونُ أَوَّلَ مَنْ بُعِثَ أَوْ فِي
>   أَوَّلِ مَنْ بُعِثَ فَإِذَا مُوسَى عَلَيْهِ السَّلاَمُ آخِذٌ
>   بِالْعَرْشِ فَلاَ أَدْرِي أَحُوسِبَ بِصَعْقَتِهِ يَوْمَ الطُّورِ أَوْ
>   بُعِثَ قَبْلِي وَلاَ أَقُولُ إِنَّ أَحَدًا أَفْضَلُ مِنْ يُونُسَ بْنِ
>   مَتَّى عَلَيْهِ السَّلاَمُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> [sahih muslim 43:209](https://sunnah.com/muslim/43/209)

Comment: But none of them say he is the best man. It says he is the leader which I accept.

Comment: @Sadiq what i understand from the hadith myself that he is the best , this is my opinion ... i think i read it somewhere ... :) 
anyway the world " سيد " could mean the best one :)
and looking to what he get in the jannah .. the best place and such thing and he is the imam of prophets .. !
do you thing alll this doesn't mean he is the best ? :)

Comment: Leader doesn't necessary mean he is the best. For example, a person in time of moses was declared better than mosses even though mosses was the leader.

Comment: @Sadiq what about getting the best place in jannah .. and being the imam of prophets :) ?

Comment: Your comments should be added to your answer as is your answer is only a list of evidences. Note that the English translations often don't make up the point which in the Arabic original shows what you intend to proof by quoting them therefore commenting them is highly recommended!